# Representing an equation in the laplace domain

Tags: laplace-transform

The equation below represents how the conductance of a sensor changes with respect to a change in carbon dioxide level:

> $$\text{Conductance} = A + Bx - Bx e^{-Ct}$$

where $A,B,C$ are constants, $x$ is the concentration and $t$ is the time.

Question is how to represent this formula using a transfer function so that a change in conductance can be observed due to a change in concentration?

Comment: I don't understand why don't you use directly your equation. Why you want to use the transfer function?

Comment: It's because I need to design a linear controller (PID or MPC) for the system. Can't be done with the non-linear system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can say is that the transfer function is the ratio between the output and the input in a system. This mean if you call $\rho$ the conductance and $x$ the concentration, you have: $$H(s)=\frac{\rho(s)}{x(s)}$$ So you get: $$H(s)=\frac{As+AC+BCx}{xs(s+C)}$$ considering you did the Laplace transform respect to the time $t$. If you have an input $x(t)$, your output will be:
$$\rho(s)=H(s)x(s)$$